# create a custom numeric arff weka

Tags: weka, naivebayes

Hello I want to create a following cusotm numeric arff in WEKA. I saw some examples of arff but still confused How I model my problem in arff. I am trying to use it for naive bayes classifier.

```
attributes = {long, sweet, colour}
long = {yes, no}
sweet = {yes, no}
colour = {yellow, other}
fruits = {banana, orange, other}

for example I have 400 instances of 
long(yes) , banana
350 of 
sweet(yes), banana
and 450 of
yellow(yes), banana
```

like wise for orange and other fruits.HOw do  I model this in arff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have never created one ARFF file from scratch, the easiest way is to put your data into a CSV file instead, open it from the weka explorer and save it as ARFF. The attributes will be handled appropriately. From there, it will be easier to modify your created ARFF, if needed.